How to use Azuma-Hoeffding inequality for the multiplication of two or more Bernoulli random variables?
Suppose $X_1$ and $X_2$ are two Bernoulli random variables with parameters $p_1$ and $p_2$. Now, we define a stochastic process where at each period $t\in [T]$, we observe $X_{t1}$ and $X_{t2}$ where $X_{ti}$ has the same distribution as $X_i$.
The conventional Azuma-Hoeffding inequality provides a high probability bound on $\left|\sum_{t=1}^T X_{ti}-p_i\right|$. Since the product of two (multiple) Bernoulli random variables is a Bernoulli random variable, I am wondering if we can again use Azuma-Hoeffding inequality to find upper bound on $\left|\sum_{t=1}^T X_{t1}X_{t2}-p_1p_2\right|$. If the answer is yes, then with probability of $2\delta$ will have:
$$
\left|\sum_{t=1}^T X_{t1}X_{t2}-p_1p_2\right| \le \sqrt{ \frac{T}{2} \log\left(\frac{1}{\delta}\right) }.
$$
As another approach, we can define $\epsilon_{ti}=X_{ti}-p_{i}$. $\epsilon_{ti}$ is centred Bernoulli r.v. Now, we can use $\epsilon_{ti}$ as follows:
$$
\left|\sum_{t=1}^T X_{t1}(\epsilon_{t2}+p_2)-p_1p_2\right| \le 
\left|\sum_{t=1}^T X_{t1}-p_1\right|+\left|\sum_{t=1}^T X_{t1}\epsilon_{ti}\right|
\le
2\sqrt{ \frac{T}{2} \log\left(\frac{1}{\delta}\right) }.
$$
I have found two upper bounds and I do not know which one is correct. I would be thankful if you help me know if the second approach is correct.

Independence or correlation properties need to be specified. Also, your notation would be easier to understand if you used $X_t$ and $Y_t$. I think you are interested in $$\left|\sum_{t=1}^TX_tY_t-pq\right|$$ Most concentration bounds are for iid random variables, if ${X_tY_t}_{t=1}^T$ are iid with mean $pq$ then you are done. This is the same as defining $W_t=X_tY_t$ for all $t$.
